# Session Message Redirect in separate function

Tags: redirect, session, messages

Before redirecting I set an error message on the session like this

```
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setError('ERROR::Please enter all fields');
    session_write_close();
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
```

This works just fine but if I do that from a separate methods the message is not set to the session

e.g

```
protected function _RedirectWithError($errorMessage)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setError('ERROR::' + $errorMessage);
        session_write_close();
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

somewhere else:
    $this->_RedirectWithError("foobar");
    return;
```

I wonder why the session message is not working in this case?

Comment: Maybe it's the place where you call the function? Do you do it in a controller? Or in the admin area? Also, not sure if `session_write_close()` is actually necessary

Comment: i call it in a Controller